# jquery plugin bug in sarfari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a really strange bug which is only occurring in safari [Click here](http://bodyworksforme.com/testing/ExpressionEngine/index.php) if you down to the upload your photos section and slide through the carousel, you'll notice the bottom section of the Polaroid stays stationary when you slide of the carousel, this is only occurring in safari for some reason, i'm 100% what's causing the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what exactly causing the problem, but if you give #container a height of 225px it's fixed.